# Bash Ping to return 'alive' IP addresses

Tags: bash, ping

(Disclaimer- I know this can be done more easily with `nmap`, but its supposed to be practice for bash shell scripting).

```
$ scriptname 192.168.42 18 23 

Checking: 192.168.42.18 19 20 21 22 23 

Live hosts: 
 192.168.42.21 
 192.168.42.22 

There were: 
 5 alive hosts 
 1 not alive hosts 
 found through the use of 'ping'.
```

Above is what I want the output to look like. 'Checking: ...' will list whatever IP is being checked. All of the Live ones will be listed under "Live Hosts" and then running totals for alive and not-alive.

Here is what I have so far

```
for i in `seq ${2} ${3}`    
do
    ping -c 1 -t 1 ${1}.${i} > /dev/null 2>&1;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Live hosts: \n ${1}.${i}"; LIVECOUNT=$( ???? )
    fi
done
```

The `LIVECOUNT=$( ???? )` because I don't know what to put in it. I'm not sure how to keep a running total for living/non living ones. The 'Live Hosts' and 'There were' sections don't need to appear until the checking is complete.

Comment: Just use `nmap`. Really. It's made to do stuff like this.

Comment: I concur with ChrisDown. Use either `nmap` or `fing`.

Comment: BTW, what you have with the printing of "Live hosts" is going to be printed every time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your first question is `LIVECOUNT=$((LIVECOUNT+1))`. This arithmetic expansion, shown by double parens: $(()), to increment the variable LIVECOUNT by one each time the ping command returns 0 for success.

The short answer to figuring out the total number of hosts is to subtract the lower address (${2}) from the upper address (${3}) and then add one to get the total hosts.

So:

```
#!/bin/bash
CHECKING=${1}.
LIVEHOSTS=""
LIVECOUNT=0
TOTALHOSTS=$(($3 - $2 + 1))
for i in `seq ${2} ${3}`
do
    CHECKING="$CHECKING${i} "
    ping -c 1 -t 1 ${1}.${i} > /dev/null 2>&1;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        LIVEHOSTS="$LIVEHOSTS \n ${1}.${i}"
        LIVECOUNT=$((LIVECOUNT+1))
    fi
done
echo ""
echo "Checking: $CHECKING"
echo ""
echo "Live hosts:"
echo -e "$LIVEHOSTS"
echo ""
echo "There were:"
echo "$LIVECOUNT alive hosts"
echo "$((TOTALHOSTS - $LIVECOUNT)) not alive hosts"
echo "found through the use of ping"
```

Note the following:
$CHECKING is a string that starts with the subnet given as parameter 1 ${1} and then adds the current host number ${i} for each iteration of the do loop.

Because of the way you have this formatted (with the "Checking: " line ahead of the "Live hosts:" line) it seemed easier to keep the live hosts in a string (similar to $CHECKING), so that's what $LIVEHOSTS is.

$LIVEHOSTS and $LIVECOUNT are initialized at blank and zero to make it clear what's going on; this isn't strictly speaking, required.

Note the use of echo -e when $LIVEHOSTS is output. That's to make the \n work as a newline.

EDIT: To show what IP is currently being checked and not a list at the end, replace `CHECKING="$CHECKING${i} "` with `echo "Checking $CHECKING${i}"` and delete or comment out the line `echo "Checking: $CHECKING"`. Since the `echo` is *inside* the `do` loop, it will get printed on every pass, using the then-current value of $i. (This is the same thing @slm pointed out about your use of `echo "Live hosts"` in your original script.)